# What is this game featuring plastic squares with numbers in each corner?

Tags: identify-this-game

What is the name of the game where there are 120 cream-colored plastic squares about an inch and a half on each side with a single number in each corner?  The numbers range from 0 to 5. I do know that Toys R Us doesn't recognize it, so it must be an older game.

If I knew what this game is called, I'd also like to find the instructions for how to play it.

Answer (score 5):

[Quad-Ominos](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/4788/quad-ominos) by [Pressman Toy Corporation](http://catalog.pressmantoy.com/), perhaps? [The rules, in English and French](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/7025/quad-ominos-rules-english-french-doc), can also be found linked from that page.